# Android Test Station stuck on queued state

Tags: android, android-tv, cts

I am trying to run compatibility test suite on my android device by using android test station and stuck on queued state inside android test station.
I am not understanding is here any resources downloading or there is any other problem.
Can anyone please help me in this??
I am following the https://source.android.com/compatibility/tests/development/android-test-station/ats-user-guide for ats setup and using the cts.zip file from https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/downloads .
Android version - 9
using java on host - jdk1.8
cts version - 9
mtt version - 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using adb over ethernet, issue was present in mtt. It was linked to the fact that device serial seen from adb was ip.

So you just need to update mtt.